# ScrollView not displaying all Contents in Homefragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-xml

I am trying to disable scrollview and show up all contents in homepage, However till no luck scroll doesn't show up all the contents.I already tried all questions regarding this but still no luck. I would appreciate if anyone could help me.Thank You :)

Here is fragment_home.xml..

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bg">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/ContainerSlider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv_latest"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv_featured"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what do you mean by disable scroll view?
Also, why do you need two recyclerviews?

Comment: Means i want to show all contents in fragment_home if scroll view enable then contents doesn't show i think.

Comment: You don't need a scrollview with recyclerview. Your layout should be possible with a single recyclerview

Comment: Can you please help me make the code work without scroll view.

Comment: yes, if you can share with me a rough design/sketch about what you want to acheive

Comment: Here is the screenshot of homepage:-https://i.imgur.com/d7pQn6F.png
I want to make homepage ui like this :-https://i.imgur.com/9LYVLJQ.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try adding to scrollview

```
android:fillportView="true"
```

You also dont need two recyclerview.. Do one with multiple view types.

With that said you also dont need that scrollview. You only need one recyclerview with multiple viewtypes.

Comment: Does your recyclerview items have defined height?

Comment: Yeah recyclerview have match_parent height.

Comment: No not the recyclerview. The recyclerview items. They should have a defined height for this to work. Try defining a height in dp.

Comment: I see you marked my answer as correct. Does that mean I solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your layout can be handled well by using EPOXY, a library from airbnb.
Will make your life a lot easier.
https://github.com/airbnb/epoxy

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `NestedScrollView` instead?

The `LinearLayout` should also have a height of `match_parent` instead of `wrap_content`.

Also you should only use `weight` for views that are children of a `LinearLayout` so you can remove that for the `NestedScrollView`.

```
<NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
```

Comment: Checked with NestedScrollView still not showing all contents.

Comment: Did you make LinearLayout match_parent? Also add
android:fillportView="true"
to NestedScrollView.

Comment: Yes both width and height are match_parent.